# Connect ZeroMQ endpoints over AWS Load balancers

Tags: zeromq, amazon-elb

I am a complete newbie to zeroMQ and apologize if this question is non-sensical.

I understand that zeroMQ provides a set of communication patterns over different connection types, namely TCP. Is it possible to use a load balancer, such as the AWS ELB to pass requests between clients and the servers using zMQ?

Is this a feasible approach and would there be any benefits to it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same question.  We have a custom binary protocol that runs over SSL, that seems to work fine over ELB in TCP mode with the SSL health check.  

We are considering switching to ZeroMQ.. I guess we need to do some testing.  In general, I think it would work, but health check would be an issue since they do curve crypto and not SSL.  We would use it for REQ/REP and PUB/SUB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELB has the option of creating a TCP load balancer.  It doesn't care what protocol your running or if its encrypted or not.  It simply sends traffic to the servers who accept TCP connections on the correct port.

Whether your using your own custom binary protocol, or a ZeroMQ based protocol, you can use an ELB load balancer on the front end.

Since most of ZeroMQ's patterns are over TCP connections, everything will run fine.

Answer (score 5):

What you're describing isn't really possible using ELB or other generic load balancer, but you *can* write a load balancer in ZMQ directly.

The main issue is that ZMQ isn't a generic socket protocol - for ZMQ to connect successfully, it needs to know about each individual socket it's connected to.  Further, a generic load balancer like ELB *doesn't* speak ZMQ, so you can't connect ZMQ directly to it - in theory you could pass a connection through ELB, but it would start to break down the moment you add more than one socket on the other side.

But there are many techniques to create your own ZMQ load balancer, I suggest you [read this section of the ZMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Load-Balancing-Pattern) to see a proto-architecture they describe to handle this.  Really, I recommend you read the whole guide, lots of valuable info in there.

The basic idea is that you write a broker that receives messages on the front end, and on the back end has a pool of workers that have registered themselves with the broker.  Each worker tells the broker that it's ready for work.  When the broker sends work to the worker, it knows it's busy, and sends new messages to a different worker.  When the worker is done, it alerts the broker and passes back any results.  Then it's available for new work.

Depending on your needs, that's one pattern that could work for you, if you need more of a round-robin approach then you can just use one of the socket types that use that method of communicating, namely `PUSH` or `DEALER`.

Comment: You comment was very insightful. I clearly got the point! Thanks :)

Comment: My main concern about having my own load balancer is how hard is it to manage the load balancer and scale it horizontally on demand (using for example Elastic Bean Stalk)?

Comment: It's hard to address your concerns directly without knowing exactly what you intend to do, why you need load balancing, what your communication architecture looks like or, honestly, being an expert in the AWS services you're interested in. An appropriately designed architecture *should* scale horizontally "for free", or at least close to it. Is there a reason you're looking into ZMQ over, say, Amazon SQS which is likely to integrate into your ecosystem a little more naturally?

Comment: Being a huge fan of zmq - and loving how it's been working - it's hard to bite the bullet to tear it down and replace it - but using SQS which won't full centrally over has to be the superior solution.